# Android Studio Failed to load platform rendering library

Tags: android-studio

I have a project started from scratch on Android Studio. The layout editor was working fine. After adding the Google Play Services library, now when I open my layout XML file I get the following error in the Design tab:
"Rendering Problems: Failed to load platform rendering library"

In the Text tab, all the attributes for my TextView components have a warning "Unknown attribute android:[...]" where [...] is the attribute being declared.

Anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: try this issue in new version Android Studio 0.1.6 may be it was fixed

Comment: Thanks, I tried updating to 0.1.6 but it didn't fix it. I had to keep working so I saved my source files elsewhere, uninstalled and reinstalled, and it now works. Sorry I don't know what caused it.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Just want to add an answer that worked for me:
Changed the version of the preview from N to 23, like so:

[image]

Comment: this should be marked as the main answer! 
Thanks that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this [Android Studio rendering problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195807/android-studio-rendering-problems). It solved the problem for me changing from version L to 19.

Comment: please provide a full answer, not just a link

Comment: This issue is specific to the error which says that the Android SDK version is being different from what the project needs. The other type of "Rendering problems" error is "Failed to load platform rendering library" which the OP (and I) are facing.

Answer (score 0):

> Android Studio Failed to load platform rendering library

What i have done in my situation, i have downloaded the latest version of "Android SDK Build Tool" and my problem is solved. I believe that will solve your problem too. Well as our other friends refer to change the version of "Android API Target (Like; 24,23 and so on)" that will also solve your problem but not the exact solution, that's my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Studio version needs to be updated. Studio 2.1 supports till API 23 for rendering.
However for debugging it allows SDK version upto 26+.

For rendering you will have to use higher version Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try install other android SDK platform on SDK manager.