# Android Studio rendering problems

Tags: android, android-studio, android-version

I'm using *Android Studio 0.2.3* and when opened an *activity layout* normally, the preview should appear on the right side, so that I can switch between *Text* and *Design* mode, which should again show the preview of the layout.

But no preview is shown not on the right side neither when I'm in *text* mode nor in the *design* mode. I just get the error `rendering problems...`

When I compile everything and install the app on my device, it works without any errors. For developing and experimenting with the layout, it would still be nice if I could get the preview to work.

I have also tried to switch between different devices in the studio, but no success.

Does anyone know how solve this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this. I am having the same problem with 0.2.6 and 0.2.7. No errors and it works fine on the device but I can't get the preview working.

Comment: No unfortunately I didn't when I restart the studio the preview is working again for some time but when I start to add/modify many components I get the error again, I guess that my notebook may be to slow (it's pretty old ;)) to do the rendering thing in time or something like that

Comment: Sadly I have the error at the moment and it doesn't work at all, no matter if I restart. If I force an error in the layout it lists it, otherwise when it's correct it just says rendering problems. My pc isn't all that old or slow. I can manually edit the file and test it on the device but it's frustrating not having the preview

Comment: I've installed studio version 0.2.7 and java version 7...The problem you describe seems to be exactly the same I have but unfortunatelly I've no idea what the problem might be

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rendering problems for Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691904/rendering-problems-for-android-studio)

Comment: In my case I commented out a `TextClock` and then un commented it again, and the layout showed up.

Answer (score 530, accepted):

Change your android version on your designer preview into your current version depend on your Manifest. rendering problem caused your designer preview used higher API level than your current android API level.

[image: Adjust with your current API Level]

Adjust with your current API Level. If the API level isn't in the list, you'll need to install it via the SDK Manager.

Comment: what null?? could you give more explain?

Comment: when you preview your layout, there is a small android in the right corner in which we specify the API level, Well it supposed to be 19 , But mine was showing <null>. But I resolved that I updated the gradle to 2.0 and changed the gradle home rebuild the project and restart the studio and now its showing 19...so All set here

Comment: @Keda87 is your project  building properly? I was also getting `<null>` in Android version dropdown but got proper SDK versions after project was successfully built.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot Yes, but honestly I never get that kind of error. have you tried Nipun David solution?? I think you had simillar problem with him.

Comment: @Keda87 No, I did not get any version in drop-down until I was able to compile project successfully.

Comment: In my case, I have had to move the API level around a bit. It finally worked on API 16

Comment: hay, my preview is not refreshing thats my case, it show the preview but after i do some change to xml code it didnt refresh and apply the change, can somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 25):

In new update **android studio 2.2** facing rendering issue then follow this steps.

I fixed it - in styles.xml file I changed

```
"Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

to

```
"Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

It's some kind of hack I came across a long time ago to solve similar rendering problems in previous Android Studio versions.

Comment: doesn't work for Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar though

Answer (score 18):

1. Open AndroidManifest.xml
2. Change:

   ```
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
   ```

   to something like:

   ```
   android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
   ```
3. Hit "refresh" button in the "Previev" tab.

Answer (score 14):

I was able to fix this in Android Studio 0.2.0 by changing API from *API 18: Android 4.3* to *API 17: Android 4.2.2*

This is under the Android icon menu in the top right of the design window.

This was a solution from  http://www.hankcs.com/program/mobiledev/idea-this-version-of-the-rendering-library-is-more-recent-than-your-version-of-intellij-idea-please-update-intellij-idea.html.This required a Google translation into English since it was in another language.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 11):

**In the Latest Android Studio 3.1.3**, Dependency:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

**or**

Even in latest by 27th of Aug 18 ie

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'`
facing similar issue

**Change it to**

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1
```

This will solve your problem of Preview.

**UPDATE**

Still, in `beta01` there is a preview problem for latest `appcompact v7 library`
make the above change as changing it to `alpha01` for solving rendering problem

Comment: As of today, the problem is still present; in the build.gradle file i had -beta01 and I solved putting -alpha1; gj

Comment: The newest dependency is `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'`

Comment: Even in this Dependency, it is having the same issue. Don't know why the issue is not yet resolved even after this iterative updates.

Comment: I have the same issue. This solution saves my life.

Answer (score 11):

When I set that `android:autofillHints="" />` in .xml file, I met the issue, *Android Studio rendering problems*, so I set that `android:autofillHints="testHint" />`, this issue is gone.

Comment: Solved my problem, helps with latest android studio 4.2.1 as well.

Comment: Spot on. I had `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1`. I have no idea how did you end up finding this attribute as an error trace gives no clues. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

I have solved the Problem by changing `style.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
     <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

this was an awesom solution.

Comment: Ive been looking a solution for this issue for like a month. This resolved it! Thank u!!!

Answer (score 2):

it still happens in Android Studio 1.5.1. on Ubuntu and you can solve it simply changing a setting from Gradle:

1) on **app/build.gradle** dependencies change from:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
```

to:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

2) rebuild project

3) refresh view

Best regards,

/Angel

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, current update, but rendering failed because I need to update.

Try changing the update version you are on. The default is Stable, but there are 3 more options, Canary being the newest and potentially least stable. I chose to check for updates from the Dev Channel, which is a little more stable than Canary build. It fixed the problem and seems to work fine.

To change the version, Check for Updates, then click the Updates link on the popup that says you already have the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

In build.gradle below dependencies add:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == "com.android.support") {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion "27.+"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This worked for me, I found it on stack, addressed as the "Theme Error solution":
[Theme Error - how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52017363/theme-error-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

Rendering didn't work for me too. I had `<null>` value on the right side of the android icon. I ran

```
sudo apt-get install gradle
```

I restarted Android studio then and `<null>` value changed to `23`.

Voila, it renders now! :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just download minimum prefered SDK from SDK Manager, then build. Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your designer version and targetSdkVersion both is same.
Example : If your targetSdkVersion is 22 then change your designer version also 22, so this problem do not occur.

Answer (score 0):

Best Solution is go to 
File -> Sync Project With Gradle Files

I hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

All you had to do is go to styles.xml file and replace your parent theme from

```
 Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar 
to 
 Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your activity_main.xml .
Switch to Design view if you are in text view.
Look for the android version,with the android robo icon.
Change the android version.
Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

this issue is probably derived from the connection of the laptop to software products like AnyConnect. Killing the remote connection works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You need to put right preview code for rendering in compose

```
@Compose
method(){}


@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewSomeDialogContent() {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(20.dp),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        ) {
            method()
        }
}
```