# Rendering error android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, rendering

I've just updated my android studio to latest version 1.5.1 but it constantly giving error when preview layout xml file (even when open new project). I am using android API 23 to preview. any help is much appreciate. Thanks

```
 Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
```

My layout file (This is auto generated by android studio)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.vic.test2.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

my `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.vic.test2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
}
```

Comment: can you check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195807/android-studio-rendering-problems

Comment: you see the rounded indicate section for my screen shot ... can you Adjust with your installed API Level that

Comment: Hi I adjust to 21 or 22 giving all blank (dont have any preview)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/16APWQippnSNr0_BWqDQd36kzRA6IpbsLSHKIt0xgEFY/edit. Herer is the screenshoot

Comment: better you need to install latest   buildTool  via the SDK Mangager.

Comment: bro before you installing you just rebuild and check it once again preview

Comment: I have clean and rebuild the project. Preview in design mode give no error API 22 and bellow but if switch to text there is blank. If change to API 23 then error come again. Very strange behavior

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105634/discussion-between-saeed-and-le-khanh-vinh).

Answer (score 1):

[image]Change your android version on your designer preview into your current version depend on your Manifest. rendering problem caused your designer preview used higher API level than your current android API level.

Adjust with your current API Level. If the API level isn't in the list, you'll need to install it via the SDK Mangager.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. Can you give more detail about this? Here is my manifest? in my manifest generated by android studio there is now android API level. https://docs.google.com/document/d/16APWQippnSNr0_BWqDQd36kzRA6IpbsLSHKIt0xgEFY/edit

Comment: can you check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195807/android-studio-rendering-problems

Comment: I can see when using <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton give error but when using <Button only working fine. Is there a bug with design support library?

Comment: "Change your android version on your designer preview into your current version depend on your Manifest". how do this, my manifest file does not have any version

Comment: I found that using appcompatButton give the error The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton