# Why I obtain this "Rendering Problems" when I open the activity visualizer of this Blank Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, ide

I am absolutly new in Android development and this is my first experiment witn **Android Studio**.

So I have the following problem: I have created a new projct having the following settings:

**Minimum SDK:** API 15 Android 4.0.3 (IceCreamSandwitch)

and then chosing **Blank Activity** into the **Add an Activity mobile** screen.

The project is correctly created but the problm is that when I open the **ativity_main.xml** representing my activity it is shown into the Android visualizer but it also appear the following error message:

```
Rendering Problems
The following clsses could not be found:

    - android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)

Tip: Try to Buld path
```

I also tryed to rebuild my projet but I still obtain the same error message.

The strange thing is that into the visualizer I can see the desird output of my view (created automatiially on the project creation).

Why? What am I missing? What is the problem? How an I fix it?

Comment: This helped me when I had the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195807/android-studio-rendering-problems

Comment: @SaNtoRiaN I just read it but I can't decreate the versions into the designer preview because in the dropdown I have not other versions

Comment: Try changing the theme from AppTheme to Holo.Light.NoActionBar. This button is a circle to the right of orientation in your layout design

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself,

I have download the correct Android SDK with the SDK Manager and then I choose this SDK into the designer preview as specified here: [Android Studio rendering problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195807/android-studio-rendering-problems)