# How to fix api render error

Tags: android, mapbox

I'm trying to develop an app which i used Mapbox map api. I have searched error but i still get same error. How can i fix it ?

[Android Studio rendering problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195807/android-studio-rendering-problems) 
[image]

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="Fragments.GeoMapFragment">

    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        mapbox:access_token="@string/accessToken"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can put your xml layout it would be very helpful to understand the problem.

But actually xml layout inflator is not as good as supporting 3rd party library views. You do no need to worry about that if your app is running normally.

Comment: i have added. Yes you're right my app doesn't have a problem about working.But i want to solve it you know.