# Android Studio not rendering preview properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am working on an app in Android Studio.I created a new project and choose a blank activity to start with.I waited for android studio to do its job and after creating the project it gave me [this](http://postimg.org/image/73m3zbzlj/).Now the problem here is the layout preview is greyed out and is not looking as it looks when the app is emulated in genymotion.

What i have tried up till now

1.Tried to clean and rebuild the project

2.Tried to sync gradle files

3.Tried to create a new project

None of the above has helped.Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your API level in the preview window(it's the android symbol!) with that in the manifest!
(And let us know if it worked!)

For more:[Android Studio rendering problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195807/android-studio-rendering-problems)

Comment: I reinstalled Android Studio and that solved the problem! Thanks!