# paint.setShadowLayer error in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, rendering

Every time I run android studio, the following error report shows up:

[image: error report]

How can I solve this?

Comment: disregard it, it's just a warning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio rendering problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195807/android-studio-rendering-problems)

Comment: @Shark it's not just a warning because when I try to create shadow for a text this error is affecting the run-time and the shadow can not be created on the virtual machine.

Comment: this is a "preview renderer" warning, just ignore it, it has nothing to do with a real application run  on your virtual machine

Comment: but I can not see those shadows that I've created for a textview!

Comment: so run you app on the emulator / device, relying on the "preview" will surprise you sooner or later

Comment: may be you are trying to add shadow on view , is it true ?