# Android Rendering Problems : Using an obsolete version of the 5.1 layout library

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-5.1.1-lollipop, android-rendering

I am getting following problem while rendering XML file.

> Using an obsolete version of the 5.1 layout library which contains many known bugs: **Install Update**, **Ignore For Now**

Is there any bug or problem in New SDK.

P.S. I saw [android-studio-rendering-problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195807/android-studio-rendering-problems) but not satisfied so its not duplicate.

[image]

Is there any solution? Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: there are many `bugs` in there some are resolve and the Google Team is working on it. And may soon it is resolve.

Comment: what your theme in manifest may b some time its affected it.  @pratik bhaii

Comment: `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` @VishalPatel

Comment: @PratikButani can you click on `Install Update`.??