# Android Studio Rendering Issue Failed to load platform rendering library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I just started with android studio, installed and created a new project.
Created an Empty Activity and when I go to `app>res>layout>activity_main.xml`, I can't get to see the preview. It says -> **Rendering Problems Failed to load platform rendering library**

I tried changing API Level by clicking on android above, Tried-> **24,22,18** But all of them give me the same error.!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.app.myfirstapp.MainActivity">
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>`
```

The render works fine in Eclipse, so why not in Android Studio?
I'm using Android Studio v2.1, SDK Tools-> 25.2.1 rc1, Android Platform Version: API 22: Android 5.1 (Lollipop) revision 2

This is the **activity_main.xml** file, any help wou

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you believe there's a bug in Android Studio, please file a bug report here: https://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html

Comment: It probably is working for others so not a bug. Need help!

Comment: What kind of help do you need? It doesn't work for you, so it's probably a bug.

Comment: Try to update to latest stable 2.1.2 version.

Comment: @sJy I'm already on the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the "Design" tab of the xml and reduce the android version to use while redering from the drop down.

Take a look at this:
[Android Studio rendering problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195807/android-studio-rendering-problems)

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, that doesn't works either! I Tried 24,22,18 but no fix.