# This version of rendering library is more recent than your version of Android Studio. Please Update your Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am getting  the below error in the design editor of layout

[image]

I have selected the API version 23 on design editor.

I have installed SDK Tools with version 23

[image]

I mentioned buildToolsVersion as "23.0.1" in build.gradle

Still I am not sure why Android Studio is asking to update the Android Studio version.

When i check the Updates in Help menu. It was displayed as below.

[image]

When i change the API version from 23 to 21 in Design Editor, I am not getting any Error. But I dont understand why API version 23 is not working in the design Editor even if i have that version installed in SDK Manager.

**build.gradle :**

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.2'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.apso"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 2
    versionName "2.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
}
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    provided 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: mind updating the question with build.gradle? (app level)

Comment: Why are you even using Android Studio 0.9? It is not recommended to use any older Version than 2.0

Comment: @Superman : please check the build.gradle i have updated in the question.

Comment: Did you try this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195807/android-studio-rendering-problems

Comment: @F43nd1r : yes I agree that we should not use any old version. I just want  to know that which component in androidstudio is producing this error.

Comment: @Superman : I tried it. When i change the API level from 23 to 21. It is working. I wonder even if i have all Tools updated to 23 in SDK Manager,why it is giving error.

Comment: It is obvious, A lot has changed since `23` onward, so many of those features must ve been integrated to the newest version of the Android Studio. I wonder what's stopping you from updating to the latest stable version of Android Studio ? :/