# Render error in Android Studio 3.0 Layout Editor

Tags: android, android-studio

I just started learning Kotlin for android development and started an empty project and added an activity. I have added the required gradle dependencies as said in Kotlin docs. By default the xml file of MainActivity contains only a TextView. But when I try to preview the xml in Layout Editor it shows a "Render Error"

```
Render problem

Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error.
```

Also I'm getting this

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)


Exception Details java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.view.TintableBackgroundView
```

I have tried rebuilding the project and refreshing layout manually. But nothing seems to work.

So what do I do? I'm using Android Studio 3.0 Canary 2 with Kotlin

**EDITED:**

I have made some progress. I have found that none of my AppCompat Themes are working.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, could you please paste the content of your gradle file ? I tried addding the com.android.support, without any luck. Thank you !

Comment: Anyone else facing this issue? I'm using Canary build 5 and faced this.

Comment: Rendering failed with a known bug. Please try a rebuild.  The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer (Open Class, Show Ex...

Comment: The above running on 26.0.0-beta2 and throws rendering errors in Android Studio.

Comment: @Han - Chen chen's answer below solves this problem.

Comment: somebody reported it here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63054597

Comment: Refer this link once, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45238691/4862479

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio rendering problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195807/android-studio-rendering-problems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, check your gradle , have you added support:appcompat dependency in app/build.gradle file ?  also appcompat:design dependency

Comment: Anyways I now added com.android.support:support library also and cleaned and rebuilt my project and somehow it worked.

Comment: like @SidharthAnil said, I only just cleaned my project for Android Studio 3.1 canary 2 and it worked.

Answer (score 93):

This solution may help you.
Modify style.xml from:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>
```

to:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>
```

Answer (score 18):

I also have this problem, solved as follows: modify the `appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2` on `build.gradle` (`modle:app`) to `appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1`.

Comment: This works for me. I'm currently using Android Studio 3.0 Canary 5.

Answer (score 12):

Dude
I'm also having same issue using Android Studio 3.0, 
I got an solution by just make some changes in style file under the value folder of res.

Here it is...

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

I have added "Base." in parent to make it work properly!

Answer (score 7):

error is :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
```

change :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
```

Answer (score 4):

There is problem with version 25.4.0 of support libraries by me. I returned to version 25.3.1 and the layout render works.

Answer (score 4):

## rendering failed in Android Studio android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView

**Environment I was working on:**

Android Studio 3.0.1

**Cause was found to be in `app/build.gradle` file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24           -----> 1
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"     -----> 2

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.some_project"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24        -----> 3
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'        -----> 4
}
```

**I changed some of the respective lines to be as follows:**

```
compileSdkVersion 26                       <------------ 1
buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"                 <------------ 2

targetSdkVersion 26                        <------------ 3

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'  <---- 4
```

And I didn't need to change anything in the `styles.xml` file. Most of the answers above had suggested to change following line:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

into following:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

But I didn't want to do it. It seems like that, Google Android has moved the `Theme(s)` API from `Base` package to a more root package, when they have upgraded the API.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by upgrading the gradle plugin version to 3.0.0-alpha2 and using gradle wrapper gradle-4.0-milestone-1-all.zip.

I logged the issue in android studio issue tracker - https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/62251892

Comment: But from alpha2 I m getting instant run error...So I disabled it right now. Do you know any workaround??

Answer (score 2):

If none of the above works the try this:

- Go to Tools > Android > SDK Manager
- Inside Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK select the SDK Tools tab.
- update the Android SDK Build-Tools to 26.0.1 or the latest available.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223687/render-error-in-android-studio-3-0-layout-editor/45002903#45002903) answer will most probably solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing same issue when i tried autofill. but
This will working for me. Make sure you add these dependencies:

```
compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0-beta2"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-beta2"
compile "com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.0-beta2"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2"
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta2'
```

and

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by change the support design version to the same appcompat version. This is my sample dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'  
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
}
```

Previously i used

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0
```

'