# Renderer error in Android Studio

Tags: android, renderer

I've started a new project but I keep getting the following renderer error:

```
Rendering failed with a known bug. Please try a rebuild.  The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.  Exception Details java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ViewBackgroundHelper   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatBackgroundHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatBackgroundHelper.java:46)   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:63)   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:56)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.<init>(CustomBar.java:95)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.NavigationBar.<init>(NavigationBar.java:52)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.NavigationBar.<init>(NavigationBar.java:46)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createNavBar(Layout.java:284)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:140)
```

I'm using the latest support libraries and the latest version of gradle build tools as well. I can't seem to get the renderer working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render error in Android Studio 3.0 Layout Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223687/render-error-in-android-studio-3-0-layout-editor)

Comment: @XH6user I'm using Android Studio 2.3.3

Comment: Have you tried adding .Base to theme? Looks like it works for many people.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add below code to grade.properties and rebuild the project

```
android.enableBuildCache=false
```