# No layout preview in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am experiencing a problem while trying to see the preview of layout xml files in Android Studio. There is a string with the content: `android...CoordinatorLayout` or `android...ActionBarOverlayLayout` in the middle of the preview screen.

I tried a few things I found while searching for a solution:

1) Cleaning the project
2) Invalidating Cache/ Restart
3) Changing the API level of the editor window.

I am not sure if this behaviour first appeared after switching to Android Studio 3.

Answer (score 0):

android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout could not be instantiated

Had the exact same problem. I got rid of it by changing res/values/styles.xml to

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47572796/5242257) in Android Studio 3.0.

Everything went back to normal when I targeted SDK version 26.