# Preview stopped working after update

Tags: android, android-layout, gradle, android-studio-3.0

I Work in a Android Project and, after **Adroid Studio 3.0** update, the problems come around.

The preview of my `activities` stop showing data, the project's still building and I can install on emulator/Phone, but I couldnt' see all the changes that I made in `XML` layout, here's the error message:

```
Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error.
```

and thoses errors:

```
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
```

I readed this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223687/render-error-in-android-studio-3-0-layout-editor) and it seems to be a Gradle Problem, I tried to restored a older version of Gradle in my git repo, but the problems continues, here's my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.golfetto.golfettomobile"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "2017.11.07"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions { javaMaxHeapSize "4g" }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(path: ':componentsutils')
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: 'r05'
    compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.5.1'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'
    compile 'com.sackcentury:shinebutton:0.1.4'
    compile 'net.colindodd:toggleimagebutton:1.2'
    compile 'com.sackcentury:shinebutton:0.1.4'
    compile 'net.colindodd:toggleimagebutton:1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'br.com.livroandroid:android-utils:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.0.9'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:sprinkles:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
    compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.4@aar'
    compile 'com.antonionicolaspina:revealtextview:2.0'
    compile 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.0.9'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.bcgdv.asia.lib:fanmenu:1.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.2.6'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

EDIT:

Just to clarify, i already tried to change the theme in styles.xml, here's the change:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

for those how help, I appreciate

Comment: update your support library versions to 26.0.0 or higher. And Rebuild the project

Comment: @SudheeshR could you please be more specific, which support library ?

Comment: change your all 'com.android.support' libs to latest, that'll fix those errors.

Comment: FYI: please refer here, newest versions: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html

Comment: and also don't forget to change your compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion compatible to the support libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the same version of `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`, and `Support Library` in your build.gradle. You need to change to something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.golfetto.golfettomobile"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "2017.11.07"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions { javaMaxHeapSize "4g" }
}
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
}
```

Read an article about it at [Picking your compileSdkVersion, minSdkVersion, and targetSdkVersion](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd)

Comment: You're welcome ;). And don't forget to use the same version of `com.google.firebase`

Answer (score 0):

Just clean and rebuilt your project and it will work again.

Comment: the same as before.

Comment: Have you already added all the dependencies for other views like recyclerView.