# after upgraded to Android Studio 3.0.1, i got Rendering Issues

Tags: android

After upgraded to Android Studio 3.0.1, I got Rendering Issues - Failed to instantiate one or more classes android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout?

What is the solution for this?

Thank you

[image: layout design Rendering Issue]

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 22
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1
com.android.support:design:23.2.1
com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.6@aar
com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1
com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
com.googlecode.android-wheel:datetime-picker:1.1
org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render error in Android Studio 3.0 Layout Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223687/render-error-in-android-studio-3-0-layout-editor)

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a question here. The answers to question above might help you.

Comment: thank you @Micer , i got hints from the question you refered to, and my problem solved by using compileSdkVersion 25, minSdkVersion 19,targetSdkVersion 21,com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0, com.android.support:design:25.4.0,com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0