# Preview timed out while rendering the layout or the preview goes blank. This error frequently comes after updating to Android Studio 3.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

The preview goes blank; sometimes in preview window, sometimes in design tab also, and sometimes the preview comes but the views go unclickable.

I tried refreshing the layout from design tab, Select design surface; but it only helps sometimes. [The preview goes blank as can be seen in the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASjL6.png)

For other information, I am using constraint layout `1.1.0-beta6`.

I cannot find any specific scenarios when this occurs nor any steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: go to design and below there will be rendering problem error just tap refresh and all fix

Comment: there are no errors, only right to left symmetry warnings. And also after force refreshing, it doesn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223687/render-error-in-android-studio-3-0-layout-editor/44224495

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=android+studio+layout+rendering+error&oq=android+studio+layout+rendering+problem

Comment: [As mentioned in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223687/render-error-in-android-studio-3-0-layout-editor/44224495), I do have support design and support appcompat dependencies in my app level gradle file.