# Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error

Tags: android

My project can't render the layout in preview. My Android Studio version 3.1.2.
Im using API 28. This my **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/frame_container">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Hello World"
    android:gravity="center"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It's simple, just to print **Hello World** to layout, but it can't show. The error like below :
[image: Preview error]

I search the solve problem, the solution is using API 26. And i try, everything is normal, preview success. But i create **Fragment Activity**, the problems come back, preview can't show.
*If you have new solution, please help me!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I met the same problem recently despite it being a wizard simple project.

I tried with 23 level (Mashmallow) without any changes. I uninstalled Android Studio, reinstalled it, it made no changes, error was still there...

Then I realized the problem was coming from a dependency (probably recently updated from Google with an error). The solution is to use the previous release.

Go to File -> Project Structure -> Modules app -> Dependencies Tab. The default used by wizard during project creation is com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3

Simply modify to com.android.support:appcompat-**v7:27.1.1**

Comment: This solved it for me. I changed `build.gradle` and used `compileSdkVersion 27` and`  `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'`  Then invalidate caches/restart.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me! I am curious why an update to the v7 appcompat library broke rendering and wasn't caught in a unit test when they pushed this update

Comment: Android studio 3.1.4 uses com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc2 so I solved with @Atara 's solution. For future readers it can be the workaround they're looking for

Answer (score 5):

in app\res\values\styles.xml
change

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

([Render error in Android Studio 3.0 Layout Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223687/render-error-in-android-studio-3-0-layout-editor))

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine; just clean project and run it again.

Clean project option is under Build .

Comment: It's still same.

Comment: @syaifulhusein go with the solution above. It worked for me