# how to change default project structure dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio

every time i create a new android studio project, the layout editor will be broken because the dependency `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3` will spoil the layout editor with:

> **Render problem**
> Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error.
>
> Tip: Try to refresh the layout.

thanks to user JLC [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50876686), the problem is solved, but if i create a new project, the problem will come back

so my question is how can i change it so that every new project will use dependency `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1` instead? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio 3.0 and above then make sure you are using the same content in build.gradle like-

```
buildscript {                 
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {            
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

And for below Android Studio 3.0 and starting from support libraries 26.+ your project build.gradle must look like this-

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

For the detailed knowledge check the below docs-

1. [Build Dependencies](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies)
2. [Building Android apps](https://guides.gradle.org/building-android-apps/)
3. [Configure your build](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/)

Comment: hey thanks for answering but i would like to ask how can i change the default project dependencies so that it would use appcompat-v7:27.1.1 instead of 28.0.0-alpha3?