# Preview screen doesn't show anything

Tags: android

Sharing a new image of the problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCjhW.png)

Comment: check the render error. in preview screen there will be red sign if there is an error. it will guide you to the correct issue.

Comment: I edit the thread with an image of that. Thanks for the info!.

Comment: Already fixed thanks for the help i didnt see the red error button ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223687/render-error-in-android-studio-3-0-layout-editor#45002903

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    }
```

Comment: I add a pic in the answers

Comment: Can you share the error displayed in xml file on top right **red** color.

Comment: First i have a "REnder problem"

Comment: Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error.

Comment: Then i have this "Failed to instantiate one class or more" The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can

Comment: @XabrielNsg
Please update below changes

use:

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'

with:

buildToolsVersion '26.0.0' 

and

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha8'

everything will work fine. 

Also up vote if ans and comment is useful.

Comment: I find a solution in this web https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223687/render-error-in-android-studio-3-0-layout-editor#45002903 .. thanks for the help i didnt see the red error button !

Answer (score 0):

You should add in your activity layout the `context` and `tools` attributes on your `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

The context should be linked to your `Activity`.

Here some documentation => https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes

Comment: I add a pic over there.

Comment: Can you try to add `android:textColor="#000000"` attribute to the TextView ?

Comment: Same issue. I try with an ImageView too and doesnt show anything