# Unable to load the layout file

Tags: android-studio-3.0

**[I have already checked the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449275/failed-to-load-appcompat-actionbar-with-unknown-error-in-android-studio)** But my problem is in version 28.

**Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pankaj.socketio"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I am getting an error in the layout. Is there anything missing?

```
Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44449275/) and [Render error in Android Studio 3.0 Layout Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44223687/)

Comment: @SardarUsama This is version 28 and your reference is not about 27 and I have already checked that.