# Android Studio Design not displaying anything

Tags: android, android-studio

edit:I am new to stackoverflow so it wont let me Upload directly..Please click the link below
[Android Studio EMPTY DESIGN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBvGz.png)

It works perfectly fine in emulator and my Physical device but i can't see anything on the design Layout..
I have tried this following solutions that i got via searching google
Updated SDK
Updated Android Studio
I also tried Build>Clean Project

File>Invalidate Cache/Restart
Tried to change the API to older version like API 25 and API 26..(Currently Installed API 28)..
Still nothing works help me..
XML CODE

> 

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ball_100x100"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="127dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="399dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You can check error or warnings by clicking on red icon at top right side

Comment: @Yatin It says Render problem..Failed to Instantiate one or more classes

Comment: @SmitShah mostly you are using a custom view from an external library that the design preview can't handle but when you run the app it will work

Comment: You can check by changing api level and work out

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24523238/1172914

Comment: @Yatin Yes i tried to change to API 24,25,26,27 ..but still the same..nothing works..In the emulator and actual physical device it works fine

Comment: Edit your question to Share your layout code

Comment: @Yatin okay wait i will upload the xml ..

Comment: try to biuld once

Comment: @Radesh Sir it works perfectly if i build it for Emulator/Physical Device but While editing the layout in the design plane..It doesnt work..My design plane is COMPLETELY EMPTY sir..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answar to this thank you anyways..Maybe its a bug in Android Studio ..
Solution
Go to Design plane on top side click the themes Icon and select any Light.DarkActionBar
For example
Material Light->Material.Light.DarkActionBar..

Answer (score 0):

In your styles xml-file change this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Works for me.