# How to select other api level in Android studio?

Tags: android

I am following this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui).

I got a Render problem. By searching from web, I found that the api level should be changed to a lower version, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195807/android-studio-rendering-problems).

The problem is that I cannot select a lower api version:
[image]
How to solve it?

Comment: Can you copy and paste the render error message you are getting?

Comment: `Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error.`  like this one?

Comment: I found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449275/failed-to-load-appcompat-actionbar-with-unknown-error-in-android-studio) that may help you.

Comment: It works, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the API level on your app `build.gradle` file. Open it on `ProjectFolder/app/build.gradle`.

You can work with a stable Android API (like 27) since Android P API (API level 28) is on [Developer Preview](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms#P_preview) stage.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myfirstapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Finally, this is my build.gradle.