# Why there is a Render Problem in Android Studio 3.1.4?

Tags: android, android-studio, render

Ever since the new repositories after `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1` launched by google, all have failed to work when it comes to proper preview of the layout.
I am forced to use `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1` i.e. `alpha1`
in spite of the availability of new repositories such as

```
28.0.0-rc02 
28.0.0-rc01 
28.0.0-beta01   
28.0.0-alpha3
```

whenever i try to use any of the above mentioned ones i get the following error:
[image]

Also i have already tried changing layout but none seem to work.
Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rish.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Not that any other functionality in Android Studio is affected(as far as i have noticed) as the compiled app still runs properly but working without a preview is hard.

I know that similar questions are already out there but none of those things make sense except changing repository version.
I wonder if this my PC's problem or has it something to do with google devs.?

Comment: In your styles for the Activity, are you using an ActionBar? You can use the NoActionBar theme, then add Toolbar on your own to the XML

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195807/android-studio-rendering-problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now the issue is fixed. Using `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0` (this is stable is and now being used by Android Studio) instead of `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-XXXX`  (`XXXX` being `rc` or `beta`) would solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this problem by downloading all SDK versions that my app was using, it turned out that version 28 was not fully installed!

Comment: As of now the issue is fixed. Using `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0` (this is stable is and now being used by Android Studio) instead of `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-XXXX`  (`XXXX` being `rc` or `beta`) would solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

It looks there are some bugs in api 28 try to reduce it to api 27.
make your compileSdkVersion to 27

```
compileSdkVersion 27
```

and your targetSdkVersion to 27

```
targetSdkVersion 27
```

and also

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

full code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.rish.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

It works fine for me

otherwise change your theme to light it also worked for me.

I changed my style to Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

You can try any of Theme.AppCompat.Light style all works fine
Don't also forget to change your theme from xml layout file and manifest file then rendering problem will gone.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and solved it by changing value in 
R.values.styles.xml.

```
 <style name="AppTheme"  
    parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <!--customize your theme here-->
  </style>
```