# How to solve problem to see preview in android studio? String index out of arange: -1

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I cant see the preview of this layout, is the only with this problem, can build and everything else is ok.
Latout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PriceActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabAddCart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_shopping_cart_24" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editCode"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:autofillHints=""
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Code"
                android:inputType="number|text" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgbScan"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_primary"
                android:cropToPadding="true"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:tint="#fff"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_qr_code_scanner_24" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#2E7D32"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

the error message is:
String index out of range: -1

Details:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:1024)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:809)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:778)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.peekValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:847)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5951)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:697)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:99)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:55)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:51)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:47)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:324)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:325)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:369)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:710)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:865)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:174)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

the problem is new, is probable after i update android studio, i don't now when exactly have this problem but is only in this layout. app works correctly but the preview and content tree of design view in android studio is not showing.

Comment: Late but I have added a solution. Please check if you still have the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The issue lies in `android:autofillHints=""`. Remove `android:autofillHints=""` from `EditText` and add `android:importantForAutofill="no"`. Above `EditText`should look like below:

```
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editCode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Code"
        android:inputType="number|text" />
```

After applying above change, please close this `xml` file and re-open it to refresh the rendering of Views.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem and I found this solution to be working for me.
It seems like it might be the solution for you too.

All credit goes to Jin with their post that's available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66717456/11878061)