# Android layout not loading

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

Android layouts used to load fine on my old computer, but when I tried to run my project from GitHub on my new laptop, the app ran perfectly fine in the emulator. However, some of my layouts showed blank screen like this:

[image: layout that doesn't load]

xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/teal_700"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Google Material version: `com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1`

layout errors:
[image: layout errors]

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.lambda$createViewFromCustomInflater$0(BridgeInflater.java:259)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromCustomInflater(BridgeInflater.java:285)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:122)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:928)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:948)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1002)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:309)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:204)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1159)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1117)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:204)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1159)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1117)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:204)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1159)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1117)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:354)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:431)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:710)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:865)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:174)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:1024)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:809)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:778)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.peekValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:847)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5951)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:996)
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:87)
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:83)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:74)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:69)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createEditText(AppCompatViewInflater.java:209)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:127)
    ... 49 more
```

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:1024)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:809)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:778)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.peekValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:847)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5951)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:697)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:99)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:55)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:51)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:47)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:324)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:204)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1159)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1117)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:204)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1159)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1117)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:204)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1159)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1117)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:354)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:431)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:710)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:865)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:174)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I tried searching for those errors on the internet, but I couldn't find any answer related to my problem.

The weird thing is, it loads in some layouts, but not all of them
[image: layout that loads]

I tried building the project again, but it didn't work.

adding new xml layout file works fine, but there's a problem with the original ones.
code has no errors, and app runs okay.

Hopefully someone is able to identify the problem here. Thanks in advance

### EDIT

The problem was solved.
It was an issue with `android:autofillHints=""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching the whole internet, I finally found out the problem.
Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/66717456/14030881

As `android:autofillHints=""` didn't leave an error in the previous android studio versions that I had.
But now it does, hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

First do file-> sync up with gradle files,
If the issue has not solved after that then do
File -> invalidate cache and restart

Answer (score 0):

**Build >> Clean Project**

after Gradle Invocation Finished...

**Build >> Rebuild Project**